# oauth2Client.getToken missing refresh_token

Tags: javascript, node.js, oauth-2.0, google-api-nodejs-client

I have a small express server that has two routes. Then it writes the json tokens to a file (I know very insecure). For some reason there's no `refresh_token`. In the docs theres a comment that `offline` for `access_type` gets `refresh_token`, which is set and it's still not working

```
access_type: 'offline', // 'online' (default) or 'offline' (gets refresh_token)
```

Here's the express server, sorry if the promises throw anyone off.

```
var Promise = require("bluebird")
var express = require('express')
var app = express()

var google = require('googleapis')
var OAuth2 = google.auth.OAuth2
var clientSecrets = require("./client_secrets.json")
var oauth2Client = new OAuth2(clientSecrets.web.client_id, clientSecrets.web.client_secret, clientSecrets.web.redirect_uris[0]);
oauth2Client.getToken = Promise.promisify(oauth2Client.getToken)

var fs = Promise.promisifyAll(require("fs"))

app.get('/google', function (req, res) {
  var url = oauth2Client.generateAuthUrl({
    access_type: 'offline',
    scope: "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive"
  })
  return res.redirect(url)
})

app.get('/oauth2callback', function (req, res) {
  return oauth2Client.getToken(req.query.code).then(function(tokens){
    fs.writeFileAsync("./tokens.json", JSON.stringify(tokens), "utf8");
    return res.json(tokens)
  }).catch(function(err){
    return res.redirect("/google")
  })
})

var server = app.listen(3000, function () {})
```

Answer (score 20, accepted):

The `refresh_token` is only sent when the user initially authorizes your app with their account. So it the `getToken` function only returns it the first time (because you should store it). Added `approval_prompt: "force"` to the `generateAuthUrl` options, and I can get it every time.

Comment: I really wish this was stated more clearly in the documentation. Been pulling my hair out for hours.

Comment: @rob when I finally found out how it worked I felt the need to post this and answer it and try to save others some time. Glad it helped.

Comment: I'm just leaving this here so that anyone else who's passing by with a bald head is looking for a more hands-on experience with the google api: [OAuth Playground](https://developers.google.com/oauthplayground/). I wish Google wouldd keep these links up front and include the required information in the reference section of the documentation . . .

Comment: `approval_prompt: "force"` [no longer works](https://github.com/googleapis/oauth2client/issues/453). Instead, use `prompt: "consent"`.

Answer (score 3):

To be more precise, you only get a refresh_token back when the user saw the consent screen, AKA the list of scopes and the "Accept" button. Users will see this screen the first time they are asked to grant access, but upon subsequent trips through the OAuth flow that screen is skipped (assuming they haven't revoked access). However, you can force the user to see the consent screen again by passing &prompt=consent in the authorization URL:

```
var url = oauth2Client.generateAuthUrl({
  access_type: 'offline',
  scope: scopes,
  prompt: 'consent'
});
```